# Oracle APEX: Unexpected error, unable to find item name at application or page level

Tags: oracle-apex

Getting error: Unexpected error, unable to find item name at application or page level.

Error gives the item ID like :P1_ITEM_ID_HERE

The error does not tell the component that has the problem, other than the page. I'm unable to find any reference to the offending item when searching for it in APEX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The navigation bar linking to the page had referenced, and was setting, an item that was not on the page.

Answer (score 0):

For me I solved it by change item type from Link to plain text and save then change it again the type of item to link and add items details then it solved the error